# SQL query in C# not support Hebrew

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem when I do a SQL query with Hebrew:

```
"select ProductName From Products WHERE TypeOfProduct ='מעבד'"
```

I have `TypeOfProduct` set, that's have the value 'מעבד', but the query returns `null`.

If I replace the hebrew word in something like numbers or english words, everything goes fine.

**How do I use hebrew in SQL queries?**

Comment: What type is your database column? What about the collation?

Comment: What does the table look like in terms of collation? Can you retrieve the data correctly and display it (if you fetch the row some other way)?

Comment: SQL was designed for the Latin character set, you very likely to encounter this kind of issue with characters that fall well outside of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use Unicode by using the "N" prefix before the string i.e. N'מעבד' in your where clause...

```
    select ProductName From Products WHERE TypeOfProduct = N'מעבד'
```

You also need to make sure that your column is of type `nvarchar` and not `varchar`.

If you cannot use `nvarchar` and Unicode string you will have to change the collation of your database from `LATIN` to `HEBREW`.

Comment: Thank you Very Very much , i serached alot and i didnt find answer , finally ! Thanks !

Comment: Glad to help... If that helps mark the the answers so others can see

Comment: Just to expand on Mort's comment, if you wat to accept this as the answer you can click on the checkbox in the top left corner of his answer.